# Greater understanding of PHP and SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have used to use PHP and MySQL a lot "back in the day" to create all kinds of websites including text-based games.

Back when I was creating these project I was using such code as:

```
$query = 'SELECT user FROM users WHERE user_id = 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

To get results from the database. I realise that this is a very bad way to be doing it, my questions is what is the best way to now do SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE etc. As these will be used all over the website should I be making functions in one file and so on. I would like to know the "best/safest" way to do about doing this. I understand having SQL statements  on one line is bad as they are open to SQL injections, I would like to know what this means exactly and how to get around this problem safely.

Its mainly handling the database that I seem to not understand. As I have not been paying attention to PHP for a few years now I see many things have moved on from when I had created my projects.

I have looked around the net and have found W3Schools to be a useful resource but I would like to hear it from people that are using this everyday to find out how I should be doing things.

Overall, how do I go about safely connecting a database and how can I grab data form the database safely for the whole website to use.

This includes:

- Connecting a database
- Getting database from the database
- Echo the data from the database onto a page

And anything else that you can think of to help me understand how to structure a "safe" website.

Thanks to anyone that replies to this/these questions, I will be very active in comments for this asking more questions about things I do not full understand.

Side Note: this website will be created using HTML, JavaScript, PHP and using a MYSQL database.

Comment: Get a MVC framework

Comment: "safe" - not easily open to attack/ not easily broken. I guess that I mean by safe.

Comment: You should look for an example that'll show you how to use MySQLi and/or PDO, there are plenty around the net :) These methods, combined with data encapsulation, make your application pretty safe.

Comment: @Edwin Lambregts Thank you for your reply, like I said I have seen so many examples of people doing things different ways. That's why I have come here to ask you guys. Examples + explanations would be great.

Comment: @Darhazer Thanks for your reply, I was looking for a little more then 4 words. Any chance you could explain a little about it etc.

Comment: @Ruddy I did. Let me know if any further explanation is needed

Comment: @Darhazer Didn't realize that was you, thank you for your answer. It would be great if you could go a bit into depth with it if possible (kind of like a lesson). If that is possible that would be amazing.

Comment: An MVC framework is a good idea, but it's not an answer to the question. I believe the thinking here is that frameworks tend to contain an ORM, and it's that bit you want. There are several standalone ones, such as Propel and Doctrine - have a look at them.

Comment: I have written an answer on proper using mysqli to fetch data, maybe helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18196311/1948292

Comment: Other stand-alone ORMs worth mentioning: [Idiorm and Paris](http://j4mie.github.io/idiormandparis/)

Comment: @halfer What advice? Taking parts of my question down because you feel that shouldn't be there when I feel they should be there? As a long-time community member surely you realise that if someone "newer" wants something in the answer and changes it back from what you put, you should leave it and wait for them to learn there lesson by people flagging the question? I will leave it as you have now put it so you can sleep tonight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all start with [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and nowadays the most popular architecture for web applications is [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (you don't need to invent one, you may use some of the existing PHP frameworks, each of them is bundled with some kind of [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)).

Since you are asking about isolating the database code, the models is the first thing you should learn from the MVC paradigm. All operations on the data, including any business logic and calculations, all DB operations, go to the model classes. There are different way you may structure them. One popular pattern is the [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) - literally a class per table. I'm not a big fan of this - you may create classes after your logical entities (user, game, etc), and they may operate on multiple tables. But those classes may be build upon Active Record anyway.

If you are working with existing code, you can start with isolating the queries in objects, so all code that work with the database is in one place - then you can start restructure objects to follow the chosen architecture : User objects works with the users table, and so on... After you separated the DB code in objects, you can easily switch to PDO or other db-implementations and protect from SQL injections.

In the end I'd like to recommend few books:
[Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) - the best book about how to turn legacy code in beautiful OO solutions

[Patterns of enterprise application architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) - hard to read but has a lot of useful info

[Implementation Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000XPRRVM) - unlike books on Design Patterns, this is focused on the small decisions, literally on each line of code

Comment: If by MVC frameworks you mean, something like `CodeIgniter`, `CakePHP`, `Symfony`, `Yii`, `Kohana` - they actually aren't MVC ones. They all implement something that is close to **Model-View-Presenter**.

Comment: Interesting, I may need to buy these books. Another question as you seem to know a fair amount for this subject. Can you explain what "SQL injections" are and how they work?

Comment: @Ruddy, the question as to what an SQL injection is can easily be searched for on the web. There's more information out there already than is worth retyping again here `:)`.

Comment: @Ruddy this is one of the best explanations for SQL injections;) http://xkcd.com/327/ SQL- injections work because user entered content is not being checked and processed appropriately by the code, leaving the possibility that some of the contents the user entered actually contain valid sql-code that is being executed when you just concatenate user-content-values and sql-code together, to get around it `prepared statements` are what you want to use

Comment: @halfer Clearly didn't read my post.

Comment: @Ruddy, what part did I miss that would have modified my answer? Experienced readers here have a tricky job to balance between being helpful and encouraging self-directed research. The question of "What is SQL injection?" is well-covered on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, and it should be regarded as helpful for readers to politely say so.

Comment: @halfer The question "What is SQL injection?" was linking into this topic. It has to do with the whole thing as to why I shouldn't be using the code I put above. Its better to have them all in one place rather then spread all over Stackoverflow. As it was relevant to code I placed in the topic I feel it has a purpose being here and should remain.

Answer (score 0):

This is worth noting:

> having SQL statements on one line is bad as they are open to SQL injections

No, SQL statements on one line is fine. SQL injections come about because user input has been allowed to enter SQL without checking that it does not in itself contain (malicious) SQL. Either use *parameterisation* to prevent this (ORMs will do this for you) or *escaping*.

Comment: Oh? I thought the other day I saw some stuff about one line being bad or something. If this is true then my mistake, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for Mysqli Prepare.
Here is an example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user FROM users WHERE user_id = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($user);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("You are %s\n", $user);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

These are better and more secure than `mysql_query()`